# Is expected that header elements use different fonts?

Tags: bug, design

## h1 element

### h2 element

#### h3 element

The h2 header uses a different font, is this really expected?

- h1 font-family: body> "Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif"
- h2 font-family: h2> "DejaVu Sans Mono","Bitstream Vera Sans Mono","Courier New",Courier,Consolas,"Andale Mono WT","Andale Mono","Lucida Console","Lucida Sans Typewriter",monospace
- h3 font-family: body> Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif

Apparently only the h2 element has a specific font (selector `.subheader h1,h2`), the others are inherited  from the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be considered [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) with the new theme rollout. All three header levels use a consistent font setting.