# Why do suggested similar posts appear between title and body of a post under creation?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, asking-questions

When type in either the body or the title of a new post, it is nice that the site suggests similar posts.

But it is also annoying that the suggestions appear between title and body, which pushes the body down out of the screen,  interrupting viewing and writing  the post, and forces the cursor back to the title (imagine when I am adding tags). Is it a design problem?

Comment: I believe with the ["recent" redesign of network sites](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4902/new-site-theme-coming-soon), I believe this is in-common behavior across sites. So far on Meta, I've found a 2009 post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-and-should-more-be-done-to-encourage-users-to-search-first-and-ask-only-if, but there may be something more recent.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/responsive-design-themes-what-can-sites-customize-and-how-can-they-get-changes from 2018 hints at the layout being "fixed" -- not customizable per-site. Does that answer your question?

Comment: As far as I can tell, while the "Similar questions" box is updated as long as you type, it doesn't cause the page to scroll or the text cursor to move, nor its height is altered depending on its content (Firefox on Linux, here). The cursor moving to the title field sounds like a bug. Are you also saying that the "Similar question" box pushes the rest of the page down _when it is refreshed_ (i.e. not just when it appears for the first time)?

Comment: @fra-san I am not sure. The problems I described happen when It is automatically refreshed

Comment: The only thing I've been able to reproduce: if the title field is left empty and you start filling in the body or tag sections, the "Similar questions" box only appears after a considerable delay, pushing down the text area while you're writing in it. But this only happens once, when the "Similar questions" box is drawn; nothing moves around afterwards. I don't think it would be considered a design issue, and it may even be intended.

Answer (score 5):

I'd argue that's the intended effect. You *should* look at those posts and see if any of those are what you're going to ask, and so they should be shown at the first available place where enough information has been gathered to start showing them: where the title has been entered.